# Extending hash constant in another file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, constants

I've got a gem where in one of classes is sth similiar:

```
class Test
    TESTING = {
        :sth1 => 'foo',
        :sth2 => 'bar'
    }

    # p Test.new.show 
    # should print 'cat'
    def show
        p TESTING[:sth3]
    end 

end
```

I extended in other file

```
# in other file
class Test 
    TESTING = {
        :sth3 => 'cat'
    }       
end
```

But i need to use :sth3 in first file, as the first part of code stands.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't extend it, you replaced the hash with a new one. Here's how to fix it:

```
# in the other file
Test::TESTING[:sth3] = 'cat'
```

I recommend using methods with lazy initialization, so that you can arrange the assignments in any order:

```
class Test
  def self.testing
    @testing ||= {}
  end

  testing[:sth1] = 'foo'
  testing[:sth2] = 'bar'
end

# in the other file
Test.testing[:sth3] = 'cat'
```